# Simplify subqueries with join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I'm trying to create a report in SQL Server Reporting Services that shows the availability of multiple sites. The sites are monitored by a tool that uses a SQL Server 2012 database to store the data.
I've created a query that shows me the results and I'm wondering if I can rewrite this query in a single select without the subqueries.

My actual query looks like

```
    SELECT 
         t1.CHECKID
        ,t1.CHECKNAME
        ,t2.Startdate
        ,t2.Enddate
        ,t2.StatusID
        ,t2.Month
        ,t2.Year
    FROM 
    (SELECT CHECKID, CHECKNAME FROM CHECKS ) AS t1
    LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT        
            STATUSCHANGES.CHECKID
            , STATUSCHANGES.DATETIME AS Startdate
            , MIN(STATUSCHANGES_1.DATETIME) AS Enddate
            , STATUSCHANGES.STATID AS StatusID
            , CHECKS.CHECKNAME
            , STATUS.STATUSNAME
            , DATEPART(MONTH,STATUSCHANGES.DATETIME) as Month
            , DATEPART(YEAR,STATUSCHANGES.DATETIME) as Year
        FROM
            STATUSCHANGES 
            INNER JOIN STATUSCHANGES AS STATUSCHANGES_1 
                ON STATUSCHANGES.CHECKID = STATUSCHANGES_1.CHECKID 
                AND STATUSCHANGES.DATETIME < STATUSCHANGES_1.DATETIME 
            INNER JOIN CHECKS ON STATUSCHANGES_1.CHECKID = CHECKS.CHECKID 
            INNER JOIN STATUS ON STATUSCHANGES.STATID = STATUS.STATUSID
        GROUP BY 
            STATUSCHANGES.CHECKID, 
            STATUSCHANGES.DATETIME, 
            STATUSCHANGES.STATID, 
            CHECKS.CHECKNAME, 
            STATUS.STATUSNAME
        HAVING 
            (STATUSCHANGES.STATID IN (3)) 
            AND DATEPART(Q,STATUSCHANGES.DATETIME) = 2
        ) AS t2
        ON t1.CHECKID = t2.CHECKID
        ORDER BY t2.Startdate
```

Is it possible to integrate the first subquery `t1` in the from clause of subquery `t2`?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard without the tables and data to test on but I believe this will work for you.  I added the subquery T1 as a `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` to T2, since I've moved the table to the `"right"` side of the query.  I moved it to the right to avoid any issues with `LEFT OUTER JOINing` the whole rest of the query.  I aliased it as `RCHECKS` (`RIGHT OUTER JOIN` version of `CHECKS`).

Also why do you have a `HAVING` clause?  Those particular statements will work just fine in the `WHERE` clause and save you quite a bit of time.  The `HAVING` clause is specifically for checks against aggregates.  My guess is if you move the checks into the `WHERE` clause you query will go much faster.  I've included a modified version of the query at the bottom using a `WHERE` clause and no subquery at all.

```
SELECT 
     t2.CHECKID
    ,t2.CHECKNAME
    ,t2.Startdate
    ,t2.Enddate
    ,t2.StatusID
    ,t2.Month
    ,t2.Year
FROM 
(SELECT        
        RCHECKS.CHECKID
        , RCHECKS.CHECKNAME
        , STATUSCHANGES.DATETIME AS Startdate
        , MIN(STATUSCHANGES_1.DATETIME) AS Enddate
        , STATUSCHANGES.STATID AS StatusID
        , CHECKS.CHECKNAME
        , STATUS.STATUSNAME
        , DATEPART(MONTH,STATUSCHANGES.DATETIME) as Month
        , DATEPART(YEAR,STATUSCHANGES.DATETIME) as Year
    FROM STATUSCHANGES 
    INNER JOIN STATUSCHANGES AS STATUSCHANGES_1 
        ON STATUSCHANGES.CHECKID = STATUSCHANGES_1.CHECKID 
        AND STATUSCHANGES.DATETIME < STATUSCHANGES_1.DATETIME 
    INNER JOIN CHECKS 
        ON STATUSCHANGES_1.CHECKID = CHECKS.CHECKID 
    INNER JOIN STATUS 
        ON STATUSCHANGES.STATID = STATUS.STATUSID
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN CHECKS RCHECKS
        ON CHECKS.CHECKID = STATUSCHANGES.CHECKID
    GROUP BY 
        RCHECKS.CHECKID, 
        RCHECKS.CHECKNAME,
        STATUSCHANGES.DATETIME, 
        STATUSCHANGES.STATID, 
        CHECKS.CHECKNAME, 
        STATUS.STATUSNAME
    HAVING 
        (STATUSCHANGES.STATID IN (3)) 
        AND DATEPART(Q,STATUSCHANGES.DATETIME) = 2
    ) AS t2
    ORDER BY t2.Startdate
```

---

```
    SELECT        
        RCHECKS.CHECKID
        , RCHECKS.CHECKNAME
        , STATUSCHANGES.DATETIME AS Startdate
        , MIN(STATUSCHANGES_1.DATETIME) AS Enddate
        , STATUSCHANGES.STATID AS StatusID
        , DATEPART(MONTH,STATUSCHANGES.DATETIME) as Month
        , DATEPART(YEAR,STATUSCHANGES.DATETIME) as Year
    FROM STATUSCHANGES 
    INNER JOIN STATUSCHANGES AS STATUSCHANGES_1 
        ON STATUSCHANGES.CHECKID = STATUSCHANGES_1.CHECKID 
        AND STATUSCHANGES.DATETIME < STATUSCHANGES_1.DATETIME 
    INNER JOIN CHECKS 
        ON STATUSCHANGES_1.CHECKID = CHECKS.CHECKID 
    INNER JOIN STATUS 
        ON STATUSCHANGES.STATID = STATUS.STATUSID
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN CHECKS RCHECKS
        ON CHECKS.CHECKID = STATUSCHANGES.CHECKID
    WHERE STATUSCHANGES.STATID IN (3) 
      AND DATEPART(Q,STATUSCHANGES.DATETIME) = 2
    GROUP BY 
        RCHECKS.CHECKID, 
        RCHECKS.CHECKNAME,
        STATUSCHANGES.DATETIME, 
        STATUSCHANGES.STATID, 
        CHECKS.CHECKNAME, 
        STATUS.STATUSNAME
    ORDER BY STATUSCHANGES.DATETIME
```